# how can one show that $\mathbb{Q}$($\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt[3]{3}$, $\sqrt[4]{3}$, ...) is algebraic but not finite dimensional?

Tags: field-theory

The fact that this extension is infinite seems almost obvious and this is what makes it difficult to prove that the extension is algebraic.  I would be able to do it for a finite case by identifying an element of this extension, say x, and considering its powers which would be linearly dependent.  However, in this situation I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[4]{3}, ...)$ is the smallest field that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\{\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[4]{3}, ...\}$, for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[4]{3}, ...)$, there must be a finite $n$, such that $x\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{3},...,\sqrt[n]{3})$, which means $x$ is an algebraic element on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;\sqrt[n]3\;$ is a root of $\;x^n-3\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , so the extension is generated by algebraic elements and is thus an algebraic extension.

It isn't finite since for every $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ there exists an element in the extension of degree $\;n\;$ , namely $\;\sqrt[n]3\;$ .

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Thank you.